# how to update snowflake driver in Talend open studio 7.2

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

Snowflake has recently updated launched JDBC Driver 3.12.x . However the talend open studios is still have 3.6.3 JDBC jar.

Is there a mechanism in talend to change the JDBC driver?
I tried updating the xml file but still the JDBC driver my job was picking up 3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Talend/Modules view to modify the JDBC driver, using a custom MVN URI. This is done at the project level.

Comment: I tried this but it is not detecting the component  MVN URI path , i think i am missing something , i will keep exploring . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You said it's picking 3.12x. I am assuming its a typo from your side.

What component you are using to connect to snowflake using talend ?
If this is not the tSnowflakeConnection.

Then you have couple of other talend components like(remember you can do all whatever you are doing using these components)

- tJdbcRow
- tJdbcConnection

Now if you want to use any of the above component they all allow you to add the driver jar.
Download the intended jar of your choice and use that in the above components instead.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks yes i did typo , i. meant to say it is picking up 3.6.3. Yes i am referring to tsnpwflake connection component. Using tjdbcconnection would have been great from start of the project as the JAR management seems to be easy. I will try to use talend/Modules view to modify it.

Comment: Hi @hopels .. I tried but in the ETL we are using tSnowflakeConnection extensively. I did one thing i.e i deleted the JAR file of 3.6.3 from the installation of the Talend.  Then i tried running the build then it asked me to choose the JAR ,this time is used the 3.12.10 jar and the build proceeded.  I can see that in snowflake the latest JDBC version 3.12.10 in  connection. However post this Talend NB_LINE variable started throwing NULL value because of which i had to revert back. Is there any way we can change JAR which is being used in tSnowflakeConnection component.